# The intersection of a descending sequence of open sets with a point in common has a nonempty interior.

Tags: general-topology

If in a topological space $X$, we have a descending infinte sequence of open sets, $\{V_n\}_\mathbb N$   ($V_{n+1}\subseteq V_n$) such that for a fixed $z\in X$, $z\in V_n$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$.  For what conditions, we can assure that: $Int(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}{V_n})\neq\varnothing$? And moreover $z\in Int(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}{V_n})$.

Comment: You're not going to get much better than "there is some open neighborhood $U$ (of $z$) such that $U \subset V_n$ for each $n$"

Comment: Do you have a context? With no context, you cannot do better than the obvious answer. Perhaps with a particular topology there are arguments to characterize this in a better fashion.

Comment: you can't always assure the existence of $U$, for example if $X=\mathbb R$ with the USUAL topology, and $\{V_n\}$ is a local base for $z$, $\{z\}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}{V_n}$ by a Hausdorff property, so if it exists $U\subseteq V_n$ for each $n$, $U=\{z\}$. In conclusion it doesn't exists $U$ everytime.

Comment: Such a $U$ doesn't always exist because the interior is not always nonempty (as in your example).

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

In general: $\operatorname{int}(A)\neq\emptyset$ if and only if $U\subseteq A$ is true for some open set $U$.

In general: $z\in\operatorname{int}(A)$ if and only if $z\in U\subseteq A$ is true for some open set $U$.

---

These facts follow directly from: $$\operatorname{int}(A)=\bigcup\{U\mid U\text{ open}\wedge U\subseteq A\}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is an isolated point of $X$, i.e., $\{x\}$ is open, then of course the intersection of *any* collection of sets containing $x$ has nonempty interior.

Assume $x$ is not an isolated point of $X$. If $X$ has a countable local base at $x$ then you clearly cannot guarantee int$\bigcap _{n\in\omega} U_n \neq\varnothing$ for each sequence of open sets $U_n$ containing $x$.  In particular, if $X$ is a nondegenerate first countable (e.g. metric) connected space, then your property fails everywhere.

I believe the points you are looking for are sometimes called $P$-points. For an example, consider the point $\omega_1$ in the linearly ordered space $[0,\omega_1]$. There also exist such points in $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$, the Stone-Cech remainder of $\omega$, assuming CH or MA.